# Make Git automatically use --word-diff on Markdown files

Tags: git, markdown, diff

When writing Markdown (articles, reports, docs, etc.) it’s way more useful to use the `--word-diff` flag when diffing.

Without `--word-diff` we see a whole line’s worth of change:

```
-Luckily, Git commit templates are incredibly simple to set up. Start by creating
+Luckily, Git commit templates are relatively simple to set up. Start by creating
```

And with `--word-diff` we see that only `[-incredibly-]{+relatively+}` has changed:

```
Luckily, Git commit templates are [-incredibly-]{+relatively+} simple to set up. Start by creating
```

I’d really like Git to use `--word-diff` automatically when it knows I’m diffing a Markdown document: is it possible? I’ve started loosely reading around Git Attributes but no joy.

Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically use git diff --word-diff option for \*.tex files but not others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368060/how-to-automatically-use-git-diff-word-diff-option-for-tex-files-but-not-oth)

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a easy way to do this on the command line, but you can add the parameter to your command, or set the `--word-diff` configuration in a project, or globally. I have an alias in ~/.gitconfig:

```
[alias]
    df = diff --patch-with-stat --word-diff --find-renames
    dfs = diff --staged --patch-with-stat --word-diff --find-renames
    # more aliases
```

There is also the answer a [How to automatically use git diff --word-diff option for *.tex files but not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368060/how-to-automatically-use-git-diff-word-diff-option-for-tex-files-but-not-oth) whic is related.

Comment: No joy I’m afraid. Tried both `./.gitattributes` and `.git/info/attributes` (and also tried setting up a global `~/.gitattributes` file) to no avail :( Is this something that you’ve got working before? As in, is it actually possible? Thanks :)

Comment: Apologies - that is referrring to another part of the configuration for a filter called 'word' , ie MSword.